# switch between mvn jars and open projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working in an enviroment with multiple projects, with some projects dependent on other projects.  So say A depends on B which depends on C.

I usually have all the projects open in eclipse, so I can quickly navigate across projects.  However, when I need to load another person's branch, which may be dependent on different branches of B and C, I prefer to remove any chance that I'm accidentally using *my* version of project B and C when testing their branch.  Thus I usually close projects B and C when I want to make sure branch A is using only what is in develop (maven will load our snapshots).

However, this get's inconvenient to do often.  When I close projects B and C I need to remove them from the buildPath of A for it to run properly.  When I'm done with a branch of A and want to go back to stop using the clean maven snapshots I need to reopen B & C and re-add the projects to A's build path.  Worse, it seems like I need to manually remove the snapshot jars of B and C from maven repo before eclipse will default to using the the open projects code.

Is there a way to configure eclipse to make this more explicit?  Can I easily toggle between using maven downloaded snapshots and using my open projects code?

Comment: Do you use m2eclipse or do you generate project configs with mvn eclipse:eclipse goal?

Comment: @MichałGrzejszczak I'm using m2eclipse.  Sorry, I forgot there was any other way to do mvn in eclipse :)

Comment: If you have `Project properties-Maven->Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects` checked you should not need to manually manage build path. When you close a project m2eclipse will automatically fall back to snapshot from your local repo.

Comment: @MichałGrzejszczak it does that.   The real problem is once that's been done it's quite difficult to get eclipse to switch back to the projects once I re-open them.  It keeps wanting to use the maven jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what I would do is create separate workspaces to avoid closing/opening any projects and/or any conflicts between them.

If you're keen on using this flow, you could select A > Maven > Disable Dependency Management. After a clean build, it should use only the B,C projects in your build path.

What I suggest is you run `mvn clean install` on B and C, it will update the local repo.

Comment: I may consider the seperate workspace option.  I would be afraid of confusing my workspaces and forgetting which I was in though.  As to the other suggestion, I'm not sure if that would work?  If I disable dependency management will all the other mvn dependency still work?  If I already have a jar for B and C in mvn will it ignore the B and C mvn jars in favor of the projects while still using all the other existing mvn jars?

Comment: If you disable dependency management, all other project maven dependencies will not work anymore. Yes.

Again, I recommend just overwriting your snapshot version on your local repo. Or remove the dependencies manually from the pom file in the other workspace.

Comment: okay, thanks.  I decided I can't do multiple workspace, due to how many branches we switch between, I would end up needing 3-4 workspace.  I guess I'm back to rebuilding every project each time, something I had tried to avoid due to both the time it takes to stash my changes and recompile them, and the fact that it sometimes lead to odd inconsistent state (usually when I didn't realize I failed to pull something in an old branch).